# Best practice for listing external news in website.

Tags: content, blog, content-management, content-strategy, news

Companies often have external news coverage. For example, Company A might have articles written about them on the New York Times, CNN, etc...

What is the best approach in terms of usability to list these external news in Company A's website? Some options:

1. Link directly from news listing off to external website.
2. Link from news listing to brief detail page with a link to the external website.

Both options seem clunky / not optimal. The first one unpleasantly takes the user off-site, while the second one feels like involving an extra non-valuable step (not to mention the effort to write the short description about the actual news article).

Comment: @AlanGeorge if you're writing your own article about the coverage, sure.  Otherwise, there are copyright concerns with ripping and posting the article to your own site without permission.

Comment: @dux Understood the question in reverse; deleted my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Link directly to the external content, and open it in a new tab.  From a UX perspective, opening external links in a new tab helps with:

- Back button fatigue.
- Site bandwidth and speed.
- Measuring correct analytics.
- Keeping user flow steady.
- Cognitive fatigue from differentiating internal and external content.

This article, though a bit older, gives a good rundown of why one should take this approach:  http://uxmovement.com/navigation/why-external-links-should-open-in-new-tabs/